# Consecutive movies with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayer

Im wanting to play a .mov file once through and then straight after play a second .mov file that is on repeat. Ive tried using sleeps and timers, as well as the AVqueue player and I just cant get any of them working. Is there a way to play a video after another using playbackState or duration times?

I'm using the MPMoviePlayer to do both of them as follows (nothing complicated)..

```
    NSString *stringPath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie1" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL *url1= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath1];
    mpc = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url1];
    [mpc setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];

    mpc.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    mpc.view.frame = CGRectMake(-200, 100, 1152, 600);

    mpc.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;

    [self.view addSubview:mpc.view];
    [mpc play];


    NSString *stringPath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie2" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL *url2= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath2];
    mpc2 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url2];
    [mpc2 setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];

    mpc.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    mpc.view.frame = CGRectMake(-200, 100, 1152, 600);

    mpc.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

    [self.view addSubview:mpc.view];
    [mpc play];
```

What can I put in between these bits of code so that the second movie only loads after the first one has played through?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` register for this notification , add an observer and once you receive notification you can play next movie.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks. I just get the SIGABRT error when I try that though, any idea why?

Comment: Make sure the first MPMoviePlayer is completely released before trying to allocate a second one

Comment: Okay, no SIGABRT but the second movie is still the only one thats playing